# wso2 dataservice serviceGroup not set from .dbs file

Tags: wso2

I created a number of DataServices that I want to have bundle under a serviceGroup. I manually added the attribute serviceGroup="MyServiceGroup".

However, when I upload the dbs files the serviceGroup is not honoured; the DataSevices are registered with the same value for service and serviceGroup.

I tried it in DataServices 4.0.2 (Carbon 4.0.2).

Here are the snippets of the dbs files:

Customer:

```
<data name="Customer_DS" serviceGroup="Participants_DS"     serviceNamespace="urn:XYZ:entities:participants">
<config id="default">
    <property name="carbon_datasource_name">XYZ_DB</property>
</config>
...
</data>
```

Coach:

```
<data description="multiple services per each table" enableBatchRequests="false" enableBoxcarring="false" name="Coach_DS" serviceGroup="Participants_DS" serviceNamespace="urn:XYZ:entities:participants" serviceStatus="active">
   <config id="default">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">XYZ_DB</property>
   </config>
    ...
</data>
```

Contract:

```
<data name="Contract_DS" serviceGroup="Participants_DS" serviceNamespace="urn:XYZ:entities:participants">
   <config id="default">
      <property name="carbon_datasource_name">XYZ_DB</property>
   </config>
...
</data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer this code.

```
    /* In the context of dataservices one service group will only contain one dataservice.
            *  Hence assigning the service group as the service group name */ 

 String serviceGroupName = serviceHierarchy +
                    this.getServiceNameFromDSContents(deploymentFileData.getFile());
```

You can understand why it is being assigned as it is. (Name + serviceHierarchy). This seems to be a limitation.

Full source is [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/components/data-services/org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core/4.0.2/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/dataservices/core/DBDeployer.java)

Comment: ok, so that means DataServices do not allow serviceGrouping, but I cannot see why this limitation is enforced...

Comment: In DSS we are hosting these as an axis2 service. Usually when you deploy axis2 archive (.aar) you add all the services in the services in one archive. So there was a problem with Data Services when undeploying where all the services which related to same service group gets undeployed by Axis2 engine even though you undeploy one Data service.